# Send messages to gdb in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb

Is there a way to send messages to gdb programmatically in tasks.json? I can send messages in the debug window, but I would like to automate this.

I am using a microcontroller and openocd. I would just like to do things like re-flash the chip through gdb (remote connection) without having to type commands out every time, and integrate gdb commands into my build tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Pass commands to `gdb` with `-ex` arguments:

```
    {
        "label": "Gdb help",
        "command": "gdb",
        "type": "shell",
        "args": [
            "-q",
            "-ex", "help",
            "-ex", "quit"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

But I would propose to write a command file (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html). So you will be able to reuse it in many places. The controller's basic initialization could be interesting for debugging (`launch.json` file). Command file could be passed via `-command=file` argument.